# Load Word Excel into WPF

Tags: wpf, excel, ms-word

I would like to load a Word or Excel document into a window of a WPF application so that users can view or edit the document within the application. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: There was a MS control named "DSOFramer" which was later discontinued. You can still find it on the web somewhere and it might just do the work for you but MS has discontinued supporting it.

Answer (score 1):

You add web browser control from toolbox and then load the Word document in it.
You can even open any document that browser support e.g. Word, Excel, PDF, SWF etc...

Example Load Word

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("C:\\word.doc");
```

Example Load Excel

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("C:\\excel.xls");
```

Comment: WebBrowser is fine, but it has two problems
1. For office 2007, the default behavior is to load the document in its own instance, this loses the meaning of integrate into the WPF application.
2. The WebControl will prompt users to open or save. This is annoying too.

I actually found a ActiveX component will hosts Office application in WinForm or WPF without the above mentioned problems. But it is a paid component. http://www.ocxt.com/

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things what you can do is print the document to XPS which comes with office or Windows (can't remember which) as a printer of the name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer".

Once you have the document, this can be displayed using a view of:

```
<DocumentViewer Name="docContent"/>
```

And simply set the document.

```
System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument doc
    = new System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(
    "myDoc.xps", System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
docContent.Document = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
```

For this to work you only need to reference "ReachFramework".

As for edit support you can use the XPS manipulation strategies provided by the XPS specification.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) comes with a .NET [Windows Forms control](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/windowsforms.aspx) which can easily be used in WPF applications to view and edit Excel documents.

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: I will definitely take a look.