# Creating an Empty DataGrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I was wondering what the best way was to create an empty datagrid.

For example after you have hit new in excel, You have a grid with empty rows and columns.

I am using c# with WPF and .net 4.0.

Thank you.

Comment: DataGrids ain't spread-sheets...

Comment: ano it is just an example of what I am trying to do...

Comment: I agree with H.B..  DataGrids only display data, so using one to not display data, but behave as if data is there is counter-intuitive.  If you want spreadsheet like behavior, purchase a spreadsheet control for WPF or try to follow some of the suggestions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859641/load-word-excel-into-wpf.

Comment: It all depends on how an "empty" DataGrid is for you.

Comment: ok, so I am not sure on the best way to do this, I am using datagrids to loads data in. That is why I though it would be best to use a datagrid to create a new. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have suggested, a datagrid is not a spreadsheet, but a method to display / edit existing data. That said if you want something similar, feel free to populate a collection with default / 'empty' objects and bind that to your grid. It just means that after working with the data, you will have to define a method to capture only the edited rows. This still means that the column-bound properties of your class need to be known ahead of time.

Comment: Is this an effective way to do this? Or should I be using some other method?

Comment: Well it depends greatly on your particular application. Is there a specific class that you are creating, or are you just wanting a spreadsheet-like, anything goes, sparse group of cells? If it is the latter than this is certainly not a proper solution, and you should look into a spreadsheet control / DataType.

Answer (score 0):

A DataGrid is used to display a collection.  If you want to create an individual row DataGrid is not really the right tool.   You could but a single empty row in the DataGrid using a collection of only on row.  There is a lot of guidance on Master Detail on MSDN.   If you don't know how many columns at design time you could used a DataGrid to turn the row vertical with column 1 as name and column as value so now you have one record but with a collection of fields.